# Uniqueness of identity in arrow metacategory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

This is pg 9 Axioms of categories of Category Theory for Working Mathematician.

In arrows-only metacategory $C$, we have $\langle f,g\rangle $ pairs composable for certain $f,g\in Obj(C)$. $\langle f,g\rangle $ assigns an arrow $g\circ f$.

Identity arrow: $u$ is defined as whenever $\langle u,f\rangle $ is defined $\langle u,f\rangle =f$ and $\langle g,u\rangle =g$ similarly.

Axioms for arrows-metacategory:1) $(k\circ g)\circ f$ is defined iff $k\circ (g\circ f)$ is defined. When either is defined, they are the same object in arrow metacategory. And they are denoted as $k\circ g\circ f$.

2) $k\circ g\circ f$ is defined whenever $k\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are defined.

3) For each $g\in C$ arrow, we have $u,u'$ identity arrows such that $u\circ g$ and $g\circ u'$ are defined.

The book claims 3) is powerful as 3) implies $u,u'$ are unique.

Q: Why are $u,u'$ unqiue? I tried the following. Take any $g\in C$ arrow and suppose $u_i\circ g=g$ for $i=1,2$. Then I have $u_1\circ u_2\circ g=u_1\circ (u_2\circ g)=u_1\circ g=g$. So $u_1\circ u_2$ is an identity as well. I do not know whether $u_1\circ u_2=u_2$ or whether it is even defined.

Comment: But to be an identity $u_1$ must satisfy $u_1\circ f = f$ *for any* $f$ where the LHS is defined. Now what does this say about $u_1 \circ u_2$? And what does the $g\circ u_2 = g$ requirement for $u_2$ to be an identity say about $u_1 \circ u_2$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair The troublesome part is why is $u_1\circ u_2$ well defined. From axiom 1), I knew $(u_1\circ u_2)\circ g$ defined but I cannot deduce $u_1\circ u_2$ defined from any of axiom above. In metacategory, it makes sense as you know domain and codomain match but in arrow-metacategory, it is not clear $u_1\circ u_2$ is defined or not.  If $u_1\circ u_2$ is defined, then the whole problem becomes trivial. Can you elaborate this part a bit as I am not sure whether $u_1\circ u_2$ is defined. Thanks.

Comment: $(u_1 \circ u_2) \circ g$ requires $u_1 \circ u_2$ to be defined. That is what the parentheses mean, first you compose $u_1$ with $u_2$, then you compose that result with $g$. If $u_1 \circ u_2$ doesn't exist, there is nothing to compose with $g$, so $(u_1 \circ u_2) \circ g$ cannot exist either. Since we know $u_1 \circ (u_2 \circ g) = u_1 \circ g = g$ exists, by axiom 1, $(u_1 \circ u_2)\circ g$ also exists, which means $u_1 \circ u_2$ exists. Axiom 1 is stronger than you thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't just know that $u_1\circ g=u_2\circ g=g$.  You also know that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are identities, which means they do nothing when you compose them with *anything*.  In particular, if $u_1\circ u_2$ is defined, then $u_1\circ u_2=u_1$ because $u_2$ is an identity, and $u_1\circ u_2=u_2$ because $u_1$ is an identity.

It thus suffices to show $u_1\circ u_2$ is defined.  This more or less follows from what you have written, but let me clarify the logic a bit.  We know that $u_1\circ g$ is defined, and we know $g=u_2\circ g$ so $u_1\circ g=u_1\circ (u_2\circ g)$ is defined.  By axiom 1, this means $(u_1\circ u_2)\circ g$ is defined, so in particular $u_1\circ u_2$ is defined.  (To say $(u_1\circ u_2)\circ g$ is defined means that first $h=u_1\circ u_2$ is defined and then $h\circ g$ is also defined.)

(Note that contrary to what you claimed, this does *not* immediately imply $u_1\circ u_2$ is an identity, since you only know about its composition with $g$, not about all compositions involving it.)